# I got this fatal error while using twilio voice

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Account not authorized to call +126878****. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international' in /home/gwalioro/public_html/swifnix.com/works/call/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php:85

**Code Here**

```
 require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;
// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACf9bd660b13b0******';
$auth_token = '7e5d0992f716420dad9******';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
// A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
$twilio_number = "+12015****";
// Where to make a voice call (your cell phone?)
$to_number = "+1268784****";
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$call = $client->account->calls->create(  
    $to_number,
    $twilio_number,
    array(
        "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
    )
);
echo  $call->sid;
```

Comment: Please Reply Team

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the Error speaks for itself :) 
You need to enable International Permissions. This is made for you not to pay more, in case you don't need that.

This is what Twilio manual tells us:

> Need to make outbound calls outside of the U.S, and want to select the regions and countries you’ll allow to protect your project from high-cost routes and potential fraud?

see more in [Twilio docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180228-International-Voice-Permissions-and-how-they-work)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your Twilio account does not have permission to call the country you are trying to call. You can fix this though. The link in the error ends up taking you to international SMS permissions, so you need to allow the country you are trying to call by logging into your Twilio account and visiting this page: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions